# Stop a Windows XP taskbar item from blinking forever

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, taskbar

In Windows XP when an application that doesn't currently have the focus wants to attract the user's attention its Taskbar item blinks. Often it blinks 3 times and then stops, which is fine. However, sometimes it just keeps blinking forever. An example of that is Firefox with a new JavaScript confirmation dialog. This is really annoying if I don't want to switch to that application just now - I basically cannot focus on anything else because of this stupid blinking thing distracting me! How do I force all apps to blink only 3 times (or X times) and then stop?

Comment: Oh I remember that horrible thing, don't recall seeing it on Vista, and no problems on Win7.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this with **Tweak UI**, part of [Microsoft's PowerToys for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx).

Download and install [Tweak UI](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fca6767b-9ed9-45a6-b352-839afb2a2679/TweakUiPowertoySetup.exe) (or click [here for the 64-bit version](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/TweakUI-64-Bit-Edition.shtml)), and fire it up.  Expand the *General* section, and click on *Focus*.  Check the "Prevent applications from stealing focus" checkbox, and then click on "Flash taskbar button X times" (where you can set the number of times it flashes).

The default value is 3 - or at least on my computer it is :)

Here's a picture to show you exactly what I mean:

[image: Tweak UI Picture]

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like there's no Tweak UI for XP x64 (only 32-bit and IA64). I suspect it modifies the same registry entry Molly mentioned, which is already set to 3.

Comment: No, you linked to the 32-bit version, which is good, but I'm running XP x64 and there seems to be no TweakUI for that at all!

Comment: Dude, http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/TweakUI-64-Bit-Edition.shtml works on 64-bit computers.  It's what I used on my downstairs PC.

Comment: Ah, thanks, the second link does work for me. Unfortunately, that setting is already set to "3 times" as in your screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Start > Run > type REGEDIT and click OK.

Navigate to the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
```

Create or modify the DWORD value **ForegroundFlashCount** and set the value to 3.

Comment: Thanks, but it's already set to 3. :(

Comment: change it to  1

Comment: Doesn't help - it still keeps blinking.

Comment: Try zero? Would that work?

Comment: zero keeps 'em flashing indefinetely.