# How can I stop the taskbar from appearing on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Is it possible to stop the taskbar from appearing in Windows 7? It is set to autohide, but it sometimes flashes up on screen.

I saw this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/43014/stop-a-windows-xp-taskbar-item-from-blinking-forever) previously but it did not explain how to turn off the flashing, just to change the number of times it flashed.

Comment: That question you linked to doesn't seem to be talking about the same problem - unless I didn't understand your question properly.

Answer (score 2):

**To stop the taskbar from appearing in Windows 7?**

> Use Taskbar Eliminator to remove the
>   TaskBar completely then bring it back
>   when you need it.

For further Information about Taskbar Eliminator , go here http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-hide-or-remove-windows-7-taskbar

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Taskbar Hider](http://www.itsamples.com/taskbar-hider.html). Tested on Windows 7 64-bit.

It's really handy, you can load it on startup and use a shortcut key to show/hide the taskbar.